# Can a fuzzy hash be used as a less accurate merkle root?

Tags: hash

If I had many, say a million random numbers (technically public keys.. ~600 bytes each) and I wanted to hash them all together using a fuzzy hash, how accurately could I test that a given hash was a part of the fuzzy hash?

I could use merkle trees, but the problem is in my system, two person should be able to hash together a similar but not exactly identical number of public keys as another person has and the other person should be able to test whether it contains a given public key. And I'd really prefer not to send all the public keys to everyone.